# OKHTTP3 Intercept times out when adding header

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Hello i have a strange error wih my okhttp3 interceptor. When adding a addtional header the request ends in a timeout. When the same intercept does the same but dosn't add the header it works fine. My code is like so

```
    @Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    if (timestamp == null) {
        timestamp = DateTime.now();
    }
    //this is used when user has forgotten his password and therefore we have no password and
    // don'T need a login to piranha
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(password) && StringUtils.isEmpty(user)) {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        return response;
    } else {
        Request request = chain.request();
        RequestBody emptyBody;
        Request loginrequest;
        Response loginresponse_okhttp;
        Request return_request;
        emptyBody = RequestBody.create(null, new byte[0]);
        loginrequest = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://my-fancy-backend/login")
                .method("POST", emptyBody)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .addHeader("my-fancy-backend-user", user)
                .addHeader("my-fancy-backend-user", password)
                .build();
        try {

            if (timestamp != null && DateTime.now().isAfter(timestamp.plusHours(4))) {
                timestamp = DateTime.now();
                loginresponse_okhttp = client.newCall(loginrequest).execute();
                loginresponse = gson.fromJson(loginresponse_okhttp.body().charStream(), LoginResponse.class);
            }
            if (loginresponse == null) {
                timestamp = DateTime.now();
                loginresponse_okhttp = client.newCall(loginrequest).execute();
                loginresponse = gson.fromJson(loginresponse_okhttp.body().charStream(), LoginResponse.class);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
        return_request = request.newBuilder().addHeader("o2online ", loginresponse.getTokenId()).build();
        return chain.proceed(return_request);

    }

}
```

the request i intercept goes to an other server does this matter in any way ? or is this the wrong way to add additional headers to an okhttp3 request?

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes here to look what goes wrong with hies request.
My problem was olved by chaning

```
 return_request = request.newBuilder().addHeader("o2online ", loginresponse.getTokenId()).build();
```

to

```
 return_request = request.newBuilder().addHeader("o2online", loginresponse.getTokenId()).build();
```

and everything was fine after.